# Magmi magento extension can not be installed in magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: php, magento

When I tried to install magmi extension in my magento, i could not do it. I have install it through the **upload option**.
But it shows the below error:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
>
> Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
>
> Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
>
> Invalid stability
>
> Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
>
> Invalid channel URL
>
> Empty authors section
>
> Empty package contents section

I have referred this site [reference](http://www.bestresponsemedia.co.uk/how-to-install-and-use-magmi-for-magento/). But that is dead.
The solution for this problem in this site [reference1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/how-to-install-a-module-in-magento) was not helpful to me.

Already I have paste the magmi folder in Magento root folder with '**777' permisiion**.
[image: Screeshot]
Help me to proceed!!

Comment: Magmi is not an extension as such.

Comment: Then how can i install it @PedroKTFC ji?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magmi is actually NOT a magento extension. It is written in basic PHP, that helps to speed up the editing Magento data, by manipulating data directly to the database, thus bypassing the default Magento workflow.

Steps:

1. Download the Magmi Files, and copy to the installation folder.
2. Provide appropriate permissions to the Magmi files/folders.
3. Configure magmi with the details it need, eg, base url, and Database details.
4. Run magmi, and be happy!

Note : Rename the magmi folder name to some random name, so others cannot access easily.
OR,
Create a basic authentication system to get into magmi

You can use installation from "Understandinge". It is an easy to use-configure Magmi installation.

Comment: When you access the Magmi Installation through browser URL, u will need to setup magmi to use the installation by providing Base Url, and Database Name, User, Password. This way it will be able to handle DB transactions,as it will then have the DB credentials it needs.

Comment: @anzWhich means my magento db credentials?

Comment: [Like the details you have in app > etc > local.xml.]   <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[xxxxxx]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[xxxxx]]></dbname> ...

Comment: U need to enter these details in magmi as well... otherwise magmi will not understand which database to use, nor the database access.

Comment: I have updated magmi.ini.default file in conf folder for setting the username and password as root dn password empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78743/discussion-between-paps-k-and-anz).

Comment: First thing first, can u access magmi via. web browser URL??